# How to fix windows update error 800700A1?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

Windows update is trying to install KB3205401, however it always fails with 800700A1. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

You might find this article helpfull, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/kb3205401-december-update-fails-to-install-with/b9369e9b-2ac4-4c2c-98c3-ee45fb3cf79d

Also, The ONLY thing that worked for was this.

1. I went into the C:\Windows\Temp directory as an administrator and made a copy.
2. Then deleted all of the items in this directory (About four items were still in use).
3. Then went back to Windows Update and got the windows update from Microsoft Update / Windows Update (Rather than WSUS).
4. Installed all the updates that I needed.